# Regular expression help in python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to get the IP-address from the below string

```
Line = SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.15.3.1.2.10.10.10.10 = 6
```

And the code which I wrote is like below. I am very new and currently stuck in a problem.

```
line = "SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.15.3.1.2.10.10.10.10 = 6"
peerip = re.search(r'[A-Z]+\w\d\W[A-Z]+::[a-z]+-2\.15\.3\.1\.2\. (.*)', line)
```

Comment: You forgot to explain what "the Ip" exactly is in your string and what problem you are facing with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
line = "SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.15.3.1.2.10.10.10.10 = 6"
match = re.search(r"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) ", line)
print(match.group(1))  # 10.10.10.10
```